# Centering a div keeping the children Floating left

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 2 div's and I want one to be centered on the screen and the other one to be on the left of it's parent #MyContent (The one which is centered). But, it seems like adding a "Float:left;" to #Latest cause a DOM error, #MyContent isn't holding #Latest any longer and it shrinks leaving #Latest out of it like if #Latest was "position:absolute;" when its "relative;".

I have these:

**HTML:**

```
<center>
    <div id="MyContent">
        <div id="Latest">
            <div class="Last"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</center>
```

**CSS:**

```
#MyContent {
    position: relative;
    font-family: FontStencil;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 20px 20px 160px 20px;
    color: black;
    background: rgba(240, 240, 240, 0.2);
    border-radius: 18px;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    top: 250;
    width: 950px;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px -2px black;
}

#Latest {
    position: relative;
    font-family: FontStencil;
    float: left; /* When I remove THIS, everything works Fine BUT its all centered */
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 20px 20px 30px 20px;
    color: #000033;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 18px;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    left: 20px;
    top: 30px;
    width: 570px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 17px -5px black;
}

.Last {
    position: relative;
    font-family: SuperG;
    text-align: left;
    right: -18px;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 15px;
    color: #000033;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 18px;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    top: 25px;
    width: 500px;
    height: 415px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 17px -5px black;
}
```

Everything is position:Relative; but it acts like if #Latest is not when I add a float:left; HALP.

Comment: You want last div to be on left side totally?? Please correct if I'm wrong

Comment: #Latest on the Left side of it's parent #MyContent which I want it to be centered, #Last is a Children div inside #Latest.

Comment: take off the `float:left` from `#Latest`, add `margin:0 auto` to `#MyContent` and remove the `center` tags should do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CSS**

```
#MyContent{
font-family:FontStencil;
font-size:12px;
padding:20px 20px 160px 20px;
color:black;
background:rgba(240,240,240, 0.2);
border-radius:18px;
border:1px solid #CCCCCC;
top:250;
width:950px;
box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px -2px black;
margin: 0 auto;
    display: inline-block;
}

#Latest{
position:relative;
font-family:FontStencil;
float: left; /* When I remove THIS, everything works Fine BUT its all centered */
text-align:left;
font-size:18px;
padding:20px 20px 30px 20px;
color:#000033;
background:white;
border-radius:18px;
border:1px solid #CCCCCC;
left:20px;
top:30px;
width:570px;
box-shadow: 0px 1px 17px -5px black;
}

.Last{
position:relative;
font-family:SuperG;
text-align:left;
right:-18px;
font-size:12px;
padding:15px;
color:#000033;
background:white;
border-radius:18px;
border:1px solid #CCCCCC;
top:25px;
width:500px;
height:415px;
box-shadow: 0px 1px 17px -5px black;
}
```

Try the above CSS. **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QnxVq/3/)**

Comment: sadly I need the width to be 570px because its supposed to be a Box in the left holding a message, and in the right there will be another thinner box holding options.

Comment: you want the #MyContent centered and #latest towards left of #Mycontent. Correct?

Comment: Yes exactly, I want #Latest on the left because there will be another box on the right side, and #MyContent shall be centered to the HTML.

Comment: That one works just fine because the problem of #Latest seems fixed, but it leaves #MyContent to the left when it needs to be Centered.